# What is the correct way to include backbone & jquery into a project after installing via npm?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express

I am using Express with Jade and I installed backbone.js and jQuery via npm. Do I copy the appropriate js files into my public/javascript folder or will Jade understand if I use require() inside the view template file?

Please steer me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything installed with the package manager is available by `require()`. If you're trying to use the libraries to be rendered client-side, then you shouldn't be installing them server-side.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer as soon as it will allow me to. Do you know if the server side libs are the same as the client side?

Comment: The server side libraries are a bit different, but retain functionality that was expected in client side. You shouldn't interchange both though.

Answer (score 0):

As hexacyanide says, Anything installed with the package manager is available by require().
If you want to use packages installed via npm in the browser, you may want to take a look at browserify. Although I'd recommend to at first simply using the files provided on the backbone and jQuery websites. It's less to learn.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I will look into browserify

Answer (score 0):

NPM is only for server side JavaScript packages.

If you want to manage your client side libraries with a package manager take a look at [bower](http://bower.io/), which shares some concepts of NPM, but for the client side.

Comment: You can use server side packages on the client with browserify.